# Incomplete graph in d3.js using json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to create a bar graph from JSON data. I tried following the example [D3.js bar chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304) but my chart is only showing two of six x points and the some of the bar appear stacked behind the chart. 
The JSON looks like:

```
{"archive": [{"total_size": 13699.2, "source": "archive", "number_of_files": 136734813.0, "number_of_files_transferred": 153214.0}, 
{"total_size": 13209.57, "source": "gps", "number_of_files": 133545394.0, "number_of_files_transferred": 150179.0}, 
{"total_size": 86.94, "source": "doris", "number_of_files": 159744.0, "number_of_files_transferred": 183.0
{"total_size": 298.49, "source": "slr", "number_of_files": 1439700.0, "number_of_files_transferred": 704.0}, 
{"total_size": 212.71, "source": "vlbi", "number_of_files": 674539.0, "number_of_files_transferred": 134.0}
{"total_size": 27.81, "source": "glonass", "number_of_files": 319432.0, "number_of_files_transferred": 20.0}]}
```

(note the above is just one of many in a dictionary)

JavaScript code:

```
    d3.json("{% url "graphs" %}", function(error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;

        x.domain(d3.extent(data['archive'], function(d) { return d.source; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data['archive'], function(d) { return d.total_size; })]);

        var xvals = function(d) { return d.source };
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("GB");

        svg.selectAll(".bar")
                .data(data['archive'])
            .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.source); })
                .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.total_size); })
                .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.total_size); });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `d3.extent` improperly for setting domain on your x scale.  From the [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_extent), it returns min/max of your data and this is inappropriate for an ordinal scale.  Instead try:

```
x.domain(data["archive"].map(function(d) { return d.source; }));
```

Full working code;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .bar {
    fill: steelblue;
  }
  
  .bar:hover {
    fill: brown;
  }
  
  .axis {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
  }
  
  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
  
  .x.axis path {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 40
      },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left");

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    //d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
    //  if (error) throw error;

    var data = {
        "archive": [{
            "total_size": 13699.2,
            "source": "archive",
            "number_of_files": 136734813.0,
            "number_of_files_transferred": 153214.0
          }, {
            "total_size": 13209.57,
            "source": "gps",
            "number_of_files": 133545394.0,
            "number_of_files_transferred": 150179.0
          }, {
            "total_size": 86.94,
            "source": "doris",
            "number_of_files": 159744.0,
            "number_of_files_transferred": 183.0
          }, {
              "total_size": 298.49,
              "source": "slr",
              "number_of_files": 1439700.0,
              "number_of_files_transferred": 704.0
            }, {
              "total_size": 212.71,
              "source": "vlbi",
              "number_of_files": 674539.0,
              "number_of_files_transferred": 134.0
            },{
              "total_size": 27.81,
              "source": "glonass",
              "number_of_files": 319432.0,
              "number_of_files_transferred": 20.0
            }]
        };

        x.domain(data["archive"].map(function(d) { return d.source; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data['archive'], function(d) {
          return d.total_size;
        })]);

        var xvals = function(d) {
          return d.source
        };
        svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("GB");

        svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data['archive'])
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return x(d.source);
        })
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return y(d.total_size);
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return height - y(d.total_size);
        });

        //});
  </script>
```